# SQL table layers?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm completely new to sql so I have no idea how everything works just yet.
I have some Shops that contain Items.
I would just store the items in a table, but the Shop class has it's own variables that I have to store somewhere too.
How would one go about storing information like this?
The picture explains everything way better than I can with words:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a table for shops and a table for items, and relate them via a foreign key constraint. Each table needs to have a Primary Key which is a unique identifier (i.e. ShopID and ItemID). Then you can relate items to shops with a column in the items table, also called ShopID. In the items table define this column as a foreign key, and you've created a one-to-many relationship. You'll want to model this in your code as well.

I'd recommend doing some research on foreign keys / primary keys and database relationships...there's tons of literature so I won't go in more depth here.

Comment: He probably wants a many-to-many relationship though since shops carry more then one item usually and a particular item can be found in many shops.

Comment: Thank you for a very quick answer! I'll look into it and see how it goes :)

Comment: @Icemanind yes probably, I was assuming the simple case where the shop's items are unique.

Comment: well there's a task which requires me to find items that exist in only one shop :|

Comment: In that case you'll want to make the primary key for the items table a combination of the ItemID and ShopID. So you can enter in multiple entries for the same ItemID, but with different a ShopID. If you need to find items that exist in only one shop, you can use a group by statement to aggregate on item ID and Count(ShopID), and look for items with a value of 1 in the Count(ShopID) column

Comment: Is it possible that I'd need a third table for saving information which Item is associated with which Shop?

Comment: That's probably more clean. Just a table called ShopItems that only contains 2 columns; ShopId and ItemId. Then you can maintain a single Primary Key for the original 2 tables.